# Looking for a (httpd like) way/server to access static files (html/images etc) from my windows pc using http

Tags: html, windows, redirect, apache

I have a static html project which contains some files I want to have access to using my cell phones or laptop's internet browser.

The concept is I have a folder in my pc which contains the files.
I would hit my computer's IP through the web browser of my laptop

```
(like http://192.168.1.5/myProject/index.html)
```

and then a server (like apache httpd works for redirecting to servers) would return me the wanted file.

NOTES:
-It should be EASY and FAST to install and Configure.

Any suggestions? Most acceptable answers are for Windows and then I accept for mac!

Comment: This belongs on http://superuser.com/ i would say

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried xampp for an apache server? There is a portable app version as well.

Also iisexpress is a nice standalone version of IIS that runs under current user profile.  Not sure if there are any limitations w the bindings tho.

Comment: I thought xampp was for php. I will see if it works for my case.

Comment: Xampp will give you the whole stack: apache, MySQL, php... for Windows.  If you're just serving html..then you'll b ok.  If you want to serve Asp.net (aspx, etc) then you'll need to go w IIS.

Comment: I want to only serve static HTML, a couple of images and a couple of xml files. Does xampp need any special settings for this?

Comment: It did work!! I just put the files I wanted under the htdocs/myFolderName/ and accessed it like http://localhost/myFolderName/myFile.html   

Thanks a lot!